# Pygame how to enable and disable a function with the same key?

Tags: pygame, event-handling, key

while making a pause menu, I've noticed that I can't pause and continue the game with the same key.

Let's say that I want to do that with the escape key.
Then, if I just press it, the game will pause for some microseconds but will continue as the `pause()` function ends also with the escape key.

I have also noticed that if I change the key used to end the execution of the pause() function to a one that's different from which had paused the game, everything would work, but I don't want this.

So what should I do in order to prevent this and be able to pause and continue the game with one key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `paused` state. Implement the event handling dependent on the state of `paused`.
Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to measure the time. Calculate the time after which the pause mode should end. Set `paused = False` when the time is reached:

```py
paused = False
pause_end_time = 0

while running:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > pause_end_time:
        paused = False

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                paused = not paused
                pause_end_time = current_time + 3000 # pause for 3 seconds

        if not paused:
            # game event handling
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                # [...]

    # [...]
```

Comment: thanks, smart as always !  I just needed this ``paused = not paused`` because I used to code instead  ``paused = False`` if paused and the event's key is escape and the opposite when not paused and now it turns off this is the source of the issue !

Comment: I also used to handle events when paused inside the paused() function (separately and not in the main loop) and I realized that was messy and confusing